# Detect Part Of An String

Tags: php, regex, string

I Want To Detect A Part Of String

```
Smith-Waterman score: 275; 46.8% identity (78.5% similar) in 79 aa overlap (1-78:26-103)
```

i want to detect **46.8%** and store it in a variable as a float value

What regex should i use?

Comment: "detect", as in check if `46.8%` **occurs** in the string, or "detect" as in **capture** that value, if so using what as delimiters ?

Comment: i want to capture the value

Comment: @freshbm if u dont want to answer just dont answer NO need for this comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = preg_match('/[0-9]{2,2}.[0-9]{1,1}\%/','Smith-Waterman score: 275; 46.8% identity (78.5% similar) in 79 aa overlap (1-78:26-103)',$ab);
print_r($ab);
```